# Excel always crash when I click on a function on the screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-11

[image]

My Excel always crash when I click on a function suggested on the screen. I've updated Office through Windows Update. I've completed Quick Repair and Online Repair, but Excel continues to crash when I click on "vlookup" (or any other suggestion in the drop-down menu). Is there a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Ever tried to start excel in safe mode? Does the problem still exist?

Comment: Yes, Excel prompted me to start in safe mode, but it continues to crash whenever I click on the function from a dropdown